# Matplotlib graph is blank and code seems fine

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can someone help me explain why my graph is blank. Below is the code. I am trying to solve a problem where a customer goes to a book store with 256 bags of pennies and calculating the time it takes to count it by N number of people.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


def bag_count(N, E, T=2):
  """
  N: Number of bags
  E: Number of Employees
  T: Number of bags you can count in 1 second, 
     One person can only add two numbers at a time
  """
    count = (N / T) / E
    print("It took {} secs to count {} bags by {} employees".format(count, N, E))
    plt.plot(N, count, linewidth=2.0)
    plt.axis([0, N, 0, count])
    plt.ylabel("Time it takes to count N bags (t)")
    plt.xlabel("The number of bags (N)")
    plt.show()

def main():    
    bag_count(256,2)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one point in your plot, and you plot it with a line option, so there is no line. Add a marker to see the point. Also, the point is in the corner of your range, so not easy to see. Replacing with this makes it easier to see:

```
    plt.plot(N, count, marker='*', linewidth=2.0)
    plt.axis([0, 2*N, 0, 2*count])
```

Answer (score 0):

The plot is not really "blank", it's just that you can't see the one data point you put in.
Your `plot` basically only put **one marker** on the figure, so if that's what you really would like to do, you should consider setting your marker size to visualize the data point, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


def bag_count(N, E, T=2):
    """
    N: Number of bags
    E: Number of Employees
    T: Number of bags you can count in 1 second, 
       One person can only add two numbers at a time
    """
    count = (N / T) / E
    print("It took {} secs to count {} bags by {} employees".format(count, N, E))
    plt.plot(N, count, "x", markersize=15)
    #plt.axis([0, N, 0, count])
    plt.ylabel("Time it takes to count N bags (t)")
    plt.xlabel("The number of bags (N)")
    plt.show()

def main():    
    bag_count(256,2)

main()
```

However, only by putting more than one data points will your plot make sense.

Comment: Thanks that works. How would I go about plotting points for number of bags counted per second then so I can see more points?

Comment: You will need to use `ndarrays` from `numpy`. You can get their tutorials from their website.